# Typescript - Duplicate identifier 'beforeEach'

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I just tried bootstraping a new project with create-react-app (1.5.2)

```
create-react-app test-ts --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

and without touching anything, I 'yarn start' and I get the following :

```
<project root>/node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts
(23,13): Duplicate identifier 'beforeEach'.
```

When I put

```
'skipLibCheck': true
```

in tsconfig.json, everything transpiles without any issue.

I obviously tried on another ubuntu machine and it works just fine without the 'skipLibCheck': true in tsconfig.json

I already tried with a fresh version of node and npm, already tried

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
(npm|yarn) install
```

The error is still there.
What do you think could be wrong ?

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "baseUrl": ".",
       "outDir": "build/dist",
       "module": "esnext",
       "target": "es5",
       "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
       "sourceMap": true,
       "allowJs": true,
       "jsx": "react",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "rootDir": "src",
       "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
       "noImplicitReturns": true,
       "noImplicitThis": true,
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "strictNullChecks": true,
       "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
       "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "build",
      "scripts",
      "acceptance-tests",
      "webpack",
      "jest",
      "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using `ts-jest`? if so, it comes with its own typings (https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/index.d.ts), remove `@types/jest` from your deps.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I just removed `@types/jest` from my deps, `skipLibCheck: true` from `tsconfig.json` and `yarn && yarn start` and now everything transpiles properly.